# Failed to install kubernetes on centos

Tags: kubernetes, linux, kubectl, centos, kubeadm

Following the [official documentation](https://kubernetes.io/docs/setup/production-environment/tools/kubeadm/install-kubeadm/), I have an error when trying to install kubernetes cluster yum package.

I am on Centos 7 using yum. So I run this commands:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/yum.repos.d/kubernetes.repo
[kubernetes]
name=Kubernetes
baseurl=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-\$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=1
repo_gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/yum-key.gpg https://packages.cloud.google.com/yum/doc/rpm-package-key.gpg
EOF

# Set SELinux in permissive mode (effectively disabling it) 
setenforce 0
sed -i 's/^SELINUX=enforcing$/SELINUX=permissive/' /etc/selinux/config
```

Indeed when I am trying to run `yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl` I have this error:

```
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
No package kubelet available.
No package kubeadm available.
No package kubectl available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

What if the real problem about the installation ?

Comment: Are you check if the repository was added at CentOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I navigate to the URL, there do not appear to be any packages in the repo. Consider trying a mirror like: mirrors.aliyun.com/kubernetes/yum/repos/kubernetes-el7-x86_64